# RegEx to rewrite a multi-folder path and file name with unknown and varying folder depth

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I need to capture and rewrite a URL path substituting a `~` for each `/` ending the rewrite with a `~`followed by the file name with extension (.jpg) from the original path. The rewrite should NOT be done if the file name at the end of the path begins with "AM", "tn_" or "_cat".

This code work for a known one-folder depth:
`RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_|_cat)[^.]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=302,NC]`

Here is an example of an original path to be rewritten:
`/ImageFolio4_files/1/Casual_Portraits/abc123_789-xyz.jpg`

Here is the desired end-result:
`/ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~Casual_Portraits~abc123_789-xyz.jpg`

I need to modify the RegEx to accomodate  1 or 2 additional sub folders before the file name, and I don't know where to start. Here is an example of a longer folder path and the desired end result:
`/ImageFolio4_files/1/Casual_Portraits/Outdoors/Beach/abc123_789-xyz.jpg`
Rewrite to:
`/ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~Casual_Portraits~Outdoors~Beach~abc123_789-xyz.jpg`

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Art Minds
Pasadena, California

Comment: I don't think you can replace it for any arbitrary depth, not with a single rewrite at least (and possibly not with many either).

Comment: @Qtax Thank you for your comment.  If the folder depth was a maximum of 3 levels deep, would that be possible?

Comment: Yes, if you do a rewrite for every depth.

Comment: @Qtax I thought that multiple re-writes might be required, but I don't know how to approach the structure of the rewrite to determine the length of the folder structure before doing the rewrite. Or with multiple rewrites, how to conditionally designate the applicable rewrite as the "Last" `[L]` rewrite. Do you have any suggestions or can you point me to a resource?

Comment: `[L]` only matters if the expression is matched. See the posted answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle up to three levels you could use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_|_cat)[^./]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_|_cat)[^./]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2~$3 [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_|_cat)[^./]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2~$3~$4 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Note the change of the expression for the file name: `[^./]+` instead of `[^.]+` so that it doesn't match any additional subfolders.

Comment: Thank you. Your code looks like it should work, but after testing with two paths that worked, it suddently no longer worked and wouldn't work for the three-deep folder structure. Do you have any suggestions? Should this be included in the .htaccess file in the home directory of my web site, or the .htaccess in one of the folders inlcluded in this folder structure?